# How to program with the Object manager through PHPStorm Magento 2

Tags: magento2, phpstorm, object-manager

I'm fairly new to the programming part of Magento 2, I've been using rest calls with PHP, but I want to change method as I'm opening up a second shop. Now I would like to know if it is possible to somehow "integrate" my Magento 2 directory within PHPStorm. And when that is done, where can i find a good guide to how to start using the Object manager to programmatically do CRUD operations in Magento 2? I found the documentation of Magento 2 confusing, and don't know where to start or even how to access the object manager. When i search on the internet I found dozens of documentation for Magento 1 using the "Mage::" but that isn't available anymore, so I don't know where to start!

EDIT : I'm programming on my laptop, and Magento 2 dir is on a dedicated server, that I can acces trough SSH or SFTP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can start from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html

In most cases you should not use Object Manager, just declare all needed dependencies in constructor. see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html for more details